# React axios - TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to make a post request in my react app using `Axios`, but I get `TypeError`  every time. Here is my code:

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error =>{
                console.log('error');
            })
    }
```

and here is what I get every time is submit form

Here are my imports:

```
import './Form.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
```

It seems to be an Axios error, I checked its installation multiple times and I don't see where the problem is.
Can someone help me?
[Here is code sandbox of my problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-bose-z361d?file=/src/App.js)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error is saying that `axios` holds the value of `undefined`. Check that you're importing it correctly and not setting it to `undefined`

Comment: if you would like to create a demo in codesandbox, what would be a great help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code sandbox link.

I did some changes and it is working fine for me.

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
const reqBody = this.state;
e.preventDefault();
axios
  .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", { reqBody })
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed and imported axios?

```
npm install axios
import axios from 'axios';
```

Comment: Yes, i even checked installation multiple times, also I added my imports to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import axios from 'axios'

const submitHandler = async (e) => {
 try {
    e.preventDefault()
    const {data} = axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
    })

    if (!data) {
      return console.err('axios err')
    }

    console.log(data)
  } catch (err) {
    console.err(err.message)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, and I'm getting 'Axios err' in the console.

Comment: did you use capitalize axios?

Comment: you shouldn't capitalize it
what error are you getting

Comment: you miss the await axios